# Are there any other Unision placeholders than $VERSION?

Tags: unison

The [basic profile example](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/beta/unison-manual.html#basicprofile) in the Unison manual introduces the `$VERSION` placeholder for backups. No other placeholders are mentioned in the docs. I'm wondering if Unison provides others except `$VERSION`. I'd like to see one for the current timestamp for example.

Comment: @Rinzwind Are you sure Unison makes environment variables available within the profile? The docs mention that`$VERSION` only is available in certain fields. So seemed to me it is something replaced by Unison with an internal value.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are (currently) no other placeholder variables besides `$VERSION` that you can use in Unison's `backupprefix` and `backupsuffix` options. And to address the comments, `$VERSION` is a Unison internal value and no you cannot use environmental variables in your Unison profile.

This functionality is implemented in the Unison source in the file `stasher.ml`, in case you were feeling up to writing this feature yourself. Otherwise I think you could just accomplish what you want with a shell script. You could write a script that watches your `backupdir` specified in your Unison profile with something from `inotifytools`, and anytime a new `FILE` is created in the directory, rename it to `$(date).FILE` or something.